# Force startup a computer automatically?

Tags: java

We know how to force shutdown an computer using Java. For example, the following code works fine for force shutdown:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Now, suppose if I want to force startup a computer (which is in shut down state), at a particular time, is it possible to do in Java or any other language?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need something to trigger the startup. The best way to trigger this is Wake On Lan.

If you want to do this in Java, [this](http://www.jibble.org/wake-on-lan/) might be a good resource.

Comment: This will necessarily need a LAN connection. It would be great if _a java program_ can start a PC without LAN connection.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but as I understand it you want to run software on a PC which is turned off?

Comment: Yes... Something like that... Like, when our mobile switch on automatically, when there is an alarm set for a particular time..

Comment: No.  You need a running computer to execute the program.  This feels silly to even say.

Comment: Also, your phone is not off if it turns on on its own.  Only the screen is off and maybe the processor is in a low power mode.

Comment: Even in your code snippet you are not actually forcing a shutdown... You are just calling a system command which the user still may not have permission to execute depending on how the system is set up. One of Javas main "things" is that it abstracts you from the os. Thus that would be very difficult to do even in a more low level language, and If this is possible at all with java it would be ugly at best.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to wake on lan, there are IPMI devices that run on some server-grade hardware that is connected to the motherboard and can control power as well as provide serial console output over a network connection.  This computer is running all the time, but I'm not familiar with any you can load your own code onto.

You can control this device remotely to power control the server that is off from any language including java.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface

Answer (score 3):

If your BIOS supports Advanced Power Management (APM) version 1.2 or later, it should be possible to wake it from sleep/standy or hibernation based on a timer. On Windows an end user can do this through Task Scheduler, and if you wish to do it programmatically you can use the [Task Scheduler interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I don't know how you would do this through Java, but here is some example C code that will create a task to wake the computer up 2 minutes in the future:

```c++
#include <mstask.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    ITaskScheduler *scheduler;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CTaskScheduler, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskScheduler, (void**)&scheduler);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      ITask *task;
      hr = scheduler->NewWorkItem(L"Wake Timer", CLSID_CTask, IID_ITask, (LPUNKNOWN*)&task);
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        WORD index;
        ITaskTrigger *trigger;
        hr = task->CreateTrigger(&index, &trigger);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
          time_t t = time(NULL) + 120;
          struct tm *ltime = localtime(&t);

          TASK_TRIGGER triggertime;
          memset(&triggertime, 0, sizeof(triggertime));
          triggertime.cbTriggerSize = sizeof(TASK_TRIGGER);
          triggertime.wBeginYear = ltime->tm_year+1900;
          triggertime.wBeginMonth = ltime->tm_mon+1;
          triggertime.wBeginDay = ltime->tm_mday;
          triggertime.wStartHour = ltime->tm_hour;
          triggertime.wStartMinute = ltime->tm_min;
          triggertime.TriggerType = TASK_TIME_TRIGGER_ONCE;
          trigger->SetTrigger(&triggertime);
          trigger->Release();
        }

        task->SetFlags(TASK_FLAG_DELETE_WHEN_DONE|TASK_FLAG_SYSTEM_REQUIRED|TASK_FLAG_RUN_ONLY_IF_LOGGED_ON);
        task->SetAccountInformation(L"", NULL);

        IPersistFile *file;
        hr = task->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&file);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
          file->Save(NULL, TRUE);
          file->Release();
        }
        task->Release();
      }
      scheduler->Release();
    }
    CoUninitialize();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Assumedly if you can do this on Windows, there must be equivalent APIs for other operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to find a similar question floating around on the internet, so I'll post the links here to see if you find it helpful. (this was the thread I found: http://www.coderanch.com/t/440680/gc/interact-Windows-Task-Scheduler-Java)

First of all though, I might add that Java is a language that must run in a Virtual Machine - there are no two ways around it. I'm not well versed in 'low-level' programming, such as programming at closer to BIOS level, which is sort of where we are heading with this.

As the question was explicitly about Java, the best I could come up with from research, is (if you're really wanting to use Java for something), using the JAVA-COM (JACOB) http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/ which allows you to hook into the Windows Task Scheduler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383581%28VS.85%29.aspx via the COM language (AF

As far as I am aware, because Java needs to be in a virtual machine to run, there would be no way of getting it to do an action such as turning on a PC - let's not even get into issues of whether such an action would require administrator or above privileges.

Hope that helps.