# RE : Commands which should react on user machine

Tags: javascript, vbscript, command-prompt

Im a fresher working in dot net domain, Can any one help me to get the commands using command prompt or vbscript code to shutdown, Restart and reboot other user machines using IP Address or hostname.

If not, please give me the commands using command prompt need to add our admin rights to any user machine using IP address or hostname.

Note: It should not ask for user name and Password, The person who is performing these actions should not have admin rights.

Please help me to solve the same.

Comment: What is the actual query?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633393/force-startup-a-computer-automatically..??

Comment: Gokul, the code which you have mentioned is good. But our requirement is,  Basically using commands in command prompt we can able to shutdown or restart our machine. But for user machines or any other machines we need to do the same using command prompt,VBscript or java script. Note : We should do the actions only with IP or hostname.It should not ask for user machine credentials or admin rights.

Comment: We should not work on user end. Only in our end we need to pass the commands. It should act on user end.

Comment: Can any one help me to get the command for adding my admin rights in user machine or some other machine from my machine using command prompt.

Comment: Hi, Please understand my query, we should not do any operations on user machines or we should not ask users to do any actions on their end. Simply we need to add our admin rights or any UN , Passwrd or watever procedure, need to pass on user end from our machine through command prompt. Then we can proceed for Shutdown/Restart/Logoff

Comment: Your question was closed, because it's off-topic on SO. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) would be a more appropriate place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant users the following 2 privileges:

- Shut down the system
- Force shutdown from a remote system

Then the system can be shut down remotely with the following command:

```
shutdown.exe -s -t 0 -m \\host
```

where `host` is the hostname or IP address of the remote system.

The privileges can be granted via a group or a local policy. The settings are located under *Security Settings → Local Policies → User Rights Assignment*:

[image: User Rights Assignment]

Comment: Hi, Please understand my query, we should not do any operations on user machines or we should not ask users to do any actions on their end. Simply we need to add our admin rights or any UN , Passwrd or watever procedure, need to pass on user end only from our machine through command prompt. Then we can proceed for Shutdown/Restart/Logoff